# How to write a recursive method in java that takes in a positive or negative integer and returns the number of digits it has

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I'm trying to solve this exercise: write a recursive method that returns the number of digits in the integer passed to it as an argument of type int.   Allow for both positive and negative arguments.  For example, -120 has three digits.

This is the code I have but I keep just getting 1 when I try to pass in 121:

```
public static int recursion(int inNumber){
    //create a counter variable for the total of digits
    int totalDigits = 0;
    //base case
    if (inNumber < -10 || inNumber > 10){
        totalDigits++;
        return totalDigits;
        //recursive case
    }else{
        totalDigits++;
        return recursion(inNumber/10) + totalDigits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've switched the < and > in your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I got through fixing this code:

**1:** 
Solve the logical error and make your code more descriptive by using logical negation.

```
public static int recursion(int inNumber) {
    //create a counter variable for the total of digits
    int totalDigits = 0;
    //base case
    if (!(inNumber <= -10 || inNumber >= 10)) { //notice the !
        return totalDigits + 1;
    //recursive case
    } else {
        totalDigits++;
        return recursion(inNumber / 10) + totalDigits;
    }
}
```

Optimisation **1**: Also you can get rid of the local variable `totalDigits` because it is always `1`:

```
public static int recursion(int inNumber) {
    //base case
    if (!(inNumber <= -10 || inNumber >= 10)) {
        return 1;
    //recursive case
    } else {
        return recursion(inNumber / 10) + 1;
    }
}
```

Optimisation **2**:  You can achieve the same using `Math.abs(int)` :

```
public static int recursion(int inNumber){
    if (Math.abs(inNumber) < 10) {           //base case
        return 1;
    } else {                                 //recursive case
       return recursion(inNumber / 10) + 1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: *you can get rid of the local variable totalDigits* - good point

Comment: Thank you for this step by step process, that helps a lot. I am very new to this is that isn't glaringly apparent haha.

Comment: @trueboolean  Just a thing: you can only choose one accepted answer, not all (I noticed that you changed the accepted anwser). Nevertheless you can upvote all helpful answers. see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @leoderprofi thanks again, I was trying to check off everyone who helped I didn't realize this unchecked the previously checked answers. I really appreciated your breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

try this simplified code, using `Math.abs`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(recursion(123456, 0));
}   

public static int recursion(int inNumber, int totalDigits){

    totalDigits++;
    if (Math.abs(inNumber) < 10){
        return totalDigits;
    }else{
        return recursion(inNumber/10, totalDigits);
    }
 }
```

**output**

6

Comment: There is no need for a second argument.

Comment: @leoderprofi - Yep, just my personal preference. Your answer is good

Comment: Thank you! This is cool, and I had never seen the abs method before so I learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If you take 121,

```
int totalDigits = 0;
if (121< -10 || 121> 10){ // YES 121>10 then: 
    totalDigits++;
    return totalDigits;
```

Your logic checks if it's higher than 10, which it is and returns totalDigits (1). What you wanna do is the inverse. If it's higher to 10, recall the same function. Basicly your if/else is just inversed.

Answer (score 0):

every call of your method , you reset the value of totalDigits  , you should affect totalDigits to your function as part of your recursive call, your code should be

```
public static int recursion(int inNumber) {
    //create a counter variable for the total of digits
    //base case
    if (Math.abs(inNumber)<10) {

        return 1;
        //recursive case
    } else {
        return recursion(inNumber / 10) + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: what number did you try with?

Comment: uhm ? all numbers? oh i see what you mean it works except with negative one's my bad  !

Comment: Honestly, if you post answers with obvious errors in them, you can expect someone to call you out on it.  It's not bullying - it's an attempt to keep the quality of answers on Stack Overflow high, and that's good for everyone.  Testing answers before you post them is a _good_ thing to do.  I thoroughly recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

Look again at your if condition. 121 is larger than 10, so the condition `inNumber > 10` is true, `totaldigits++` is executed and the method returns 1.

The condition should be  `if (inNumber > -10 && inNumber < 10)` instead.